# Не могу подключиться к базе PostgreSQL Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Всем привет. Есть такая проблема, я не могу подключиться к БД. Пароль правильный, имя пользователя правильное, но почему-то подключение не происходит...

Вот код БД:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=5432;Username=test;Password=test_pswd;Database=usersdb;");
    }
}
```

Вот код программы:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            // создаем два объекта User
            User user1 = new User { Name = "Tom", Age = 33 };
            User user2 = new User { Name = "Alice", Age = 26 };

            // добавляем их в бд
            db.Users.AddRange(user1, user2);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        // получение данных
        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            // получаем объекты из бд и выводим на консоль
            var users = db.Users.ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("Users list:");
            foreach (User u in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{u.Id}.{u.Name} - {u.Age}");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

А вот ошибка:

```
Unhandled exception. Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 28P01: ???????????? "test" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|233_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.AuthenticateSASL(List`1 mechanisms, String username, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Authenticate(String username, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|215_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.UnpooledDataSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
   at ApplicationContext..ctor() in D:\AdminInfo\IT\Программирование\C#\TestsOnly\TestsOnly\MyDbContext.cs:line 14
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\AdminInfo\IT\Программирование\C#\TestsOnly\TestsOnly\Program.cs:line 13
  Exception data:
    Severity: ?????
    SqlState: 28P01
    MessageText: ???????????? "test" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)
    File: auth.c
    Line: 329
    Routine: auth_failed
```

В чём проблема? Подскажите пожалуйста. Такая же фигня происходит не только с пользователем test, а ещё и с корневым postgres

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, хорошо. Сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 0):

Читаем документацию по PostgreSQl:

28P01 - invalid password. (неправильный пароль)

проверяйте (например кодировку)

... да у Вас, кстати черными английскими буквами по белому русскому фону таки и написано в конце сообщения об ошибки:

```
SqlState: 28P01
MessageText: ???????????? "test" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)
File: auth.c
Line: 329
Routine: auth_failed
```

ну, ещё возможно несовпадение пары логин/пароль, отсутствие доступа (не настроен / нет прав) пользователя к данной БД

Comment: Ну пользователь может подключиться к моей базе данных. Через psql я могу нормально работать, через pgadmin тоже. Через что угодно, но только не через EF Core

Comment: @Freemoon ну, ошибка приведена выше. Посмотри в логах сервера. А так - ошибка авторизации. Причины удаленно сказать не могу. Нужно детально смотреть.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, в моём случае помогла переустановка Postgre SQL. Я не знаю, с чем это могло быть связано, но спасибо всем, кто пытался мне помочь)